# how to add parent class in css file?

Tags: html, css

how to add parent class in css file

sourcse css

```
.pagination {
   font-size: 10px
}
a {
   font-size: 30px
}
...............
```

To get something like this

```
.parent-class {
   .pagination {
        font-size: 10px
   }
   a {
     font-size: 30px
   }
   ...............
}
```

It should be a lot of it will automatically wrap

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the structure you have is `sass`/`scss`/`less`.

In `css`, you do it like so:-

```
.parent-class .pagination {
        font-size: 10px
}
.parent-class a {
     font-size: 30px
}
...............
```

Once `sass`/`scss`/`less` is compiled, it generates the `css` structure above.

Answer (score 0):

According to me it is not possible by plain css,
You have to use LESS...
Use separate classes rather so that it can be repeated anywhere.

Anyhow CSS for `<a>` will be applicable everywhere and only thing left is .pagination class so simply apply

Answer (score 0):

```
.parent-class .pagination{
   font-size: 10px
}
.parent-class .pagination > a {
   font-size: 30px
}
```

Comment: `a` is not inside `.pagination`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
.parent-class .pagination {
    font-size: 10px
}
.parent-class .pagination a{
    font-size: 30px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my case.
I get this css file from other website. Also need to add a parent class name as you need.

Following is an example code for Koa server.

```js
import sass from "node-sass";
import axios from "axios";

export const settingApi = (router) => {
   router.get("/api/wrap_css", async (ctx) => {
   const { data } = await axios.get(
      "YOUR CSS FILE URL",
    );
    const result = sass.renderSync({
      data: `.parent-class{${data}}`,
      outputStyle: "compressed",
    });
    ctx.response.body = result.css.toString();
    ctx.response.status = 200;
    ctx.response.set("Content-Type", "text/css");
}
```

if your file is a static file try to read the file by fs.

```js
    const fs = require("fs");
    const data = fs.readFileSync("css.file").toString();
    const compileResult = sass.renderSync({
      data: `.parent-class{${data}}`,
      outputStyle: "compressed",
    }).css.toString();
```

```css
// the compileResult string without compressed should be as following
.parent-class .pagination {
     font-size: 10px
}
.parent-class a {
     font-size: 30px
}
...............
```

Answer (score -1):

If the following HTML-Code is what you want

```
<div class="parent-class">
    <div class="pagination"></div>
    <a>Example with font-size 30px</a>
</div>
```

You need the following CSS classes:

```
.parent-class { /* define parent class properties here */ }
.parent-class .pagination {
    font-size: 10px
 }
 .parent-class a {
    font-size: 30px
 }
 ...............
```

NOTE: The position of the div with the .pagination class and the "a"-tag are not important in this case. They will be affected by the CSS rules you defined no matter where they are located inside the .parent-class div
If you want a selector that only matches the children when they are DIRECT descendants of this element, you need something like this:

```
.parent-class { /* define parent class properties here */ }
/* '>' selects all elements with .pagination class, which have a parent element with class .parent-class */
.parent-class > .pagination {
    font-size: 10px
 }
 .parent-class > a {
    font-size: 30px
 }
 ...............
```

Comment: `.parent-class.pagination` means an element that has both the .parent-class and .pagination classes, the correct way to select all elements with the .pagination that also are children of .parent-class looks like this: `.parent-class .pagination` :)

Comment: Yes, you are right, I did not check my post enough, thanks :)